# How to use input in newcommand?

Tags: document-classes, input, wrap, definition

I want to implement an insert text wrapped in some additional tags using the `\input` command. But I get `LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.`. How to do it properly? Here is my minimal reproducible example:

### style.cls - defines commands

```latex
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{style}[Some class]
\LoadClass{report}


\newcommand{\task}[1]{  % Command for defining the text that I want to insert
  \gdef\@task{#1}
}

\newcommand{\typeTask}{  % Command to insert text into some kind of wrapper
    \begin{center}
        \MakeUppercase{task}
    \end{center}
    \vspace{4mm}
    \@task \\  % Text declared using \task command
    \vspace{4mm}
    \rule{4cm}{0.4pt}
}
```

### main.tex - main tex file

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{style}
\begin{document}
\task{\input{to_include}}  % Including text from another tex file and defining as @task
\typeTask  % Inserting wrapped defined text
\end{document}
```

### to_include.tex - latex text to include

```latex
Some text
\begin{enumerate}
    \item item 1
    \item another item
        \subitem and subitems
        \subitem more subitems
    \item latest item
\end{enumerate}
```

I want to get the result corresponding to the LaTeX file:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{report}
\begin{document}
    { % Header of wrapper from style.cls
        \begin{center}
            \MakeUppercase{task}
        \end{center}
        \vspace{4mm}
    }
    { % From include file
        Some text
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item item 1
            \item another item
                \subitem and subitems
                \subitem more subitems
            \item latest item
        \end{enumerate}
    }
    { % Footer of wrapper from style.cls
        \vspace{4mm}
        \rule{4cm}{0.4pt}
    }
\end{document}
```

instead of error. How to do this properly?

Comment: the error is unrelated to `\input` or `\newcommand` you have `\\ ` after `\@task` which effectively means you ave `\\ ` after `\end{enumerate}` which will give the error that you show. Use `\par` not `\\ ` (using `\vspace` after `\\ ` is usually wrong anyway it will add space after the _following_ line)

Comment: Don't use `\\ ` after `\@task`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is produced by `\\`  if there is no line for it to end, it is not related to `\input` or `\newcommand` really.

You have

```
    \vspace{4mm}
    \@task \\  % Text declared using \task command
    \vspace{4mm}
```

so if `\@task` (which is the text supplied in the argument) has already ended the paragraph, the `\\`  here will be in error.

If `\@task` does not end the paragraph (eg if the argument was `Hello World` then you would get no error but undesired behaviour as the `\\`  would force a line break but the following  `\vspace` would not add space at that point but after the *following* line.

Almost always when using `\vspace` you want a blank line (or equivalently, `\par`) before the space to get into vertical mode.

so

```
    \vspace{4mm}
    \@task \par  % Text declared using \task command
    \vspace{4mm}
```